# Continuous Integration for IOS with Jenkins

Tags: ios, jenkins, continuous-integration, xcode7

Followed this article, http://blog.shinetech.com/2011/06/23/ci-with-jenkins-for-ios-apps-build-distribution-via-testflightapp-tutorial/ for Jenkins setup in IOS.Resulting in, Clean succeeded, xcode build succeeded, creating ipa but at the end "Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure" & Could not connect to SMTP host to send mail. Finished: FAILURE.

My Shell script is, xcodebuild -target EmailTests  -configuration Debug -sdk iphonesimulator | ./ocunit2junit.rb

Kindly help me to clear this issue.